# Retrieve list elements returned by a function in loop

Tags: r, list, function

I need to retrieve elements of list returned by a function in a loop and create a matrix using those list elements

Function:

```
function(med, days){
     i <- 0
     cnt = 1
     lCnt = 1
     value <- 0
     fx <- 0
     t <- 0
     flag <- 0
     daysList <- NULL
     valuesList <- NULL
     for(i in days){
         lambda = ((0.693)/(med*30.475))
         fx[cnt] <- c(1 - exp(-lambda*(i*7)))
         if(cnt == 1){
             prob = rbinom(1,1,fx[cnt])
         }else{
             t[cnt] <- ((fx[cnt]-fx[cnt - 1])/(1-fx[cnt-1]))
             prob = rbinom(1,1,t[cnt])
         }
         if(cnt == 1){
             tmp = days[cnt]
         }else{
             tmp = days[cnt] - days[cnt -1]   
         }
         if(prob == 0 && flag == 0){
             value = value + tmp
             valuesList[lCnt] <- prob
         }else{
             if(flag == 0){
                 value = value + tmp
                 valuesList[lCnt] <- prob
                 flag <- 1
             }else{
                 valuesList[lCnt] <- 'E'       
             }
         } 
         daysList[lCnt] <- days[cnt]
         lCnt = lCnt + 1
         if(flag == 0){
             cnt = cnt + 1   
         }
     }
     ret <- list('rDays' = daysList,'rValues' = valuesList)
     return(ret)
 }
```

Now I want to repeat this function for different inputs, so I used for loop as follows:

```
for(i in 1:300){
   days1=c(rnorm(8,mean=56,sd=3))
   days=cumsum(days1)
   res[i] <- getMedData (med,days)
 }
```

At the end I want two matrices one contains `rDays` returned by function and another with `rValues`

Can anyone please help me to create matrix in such format, Since I am new to R I am not able to find best way to do it

Comment: Im not sure what kind of values you are using as input, or the exact purpose of the function. However the for loop will need to establish an empty vector for res otherwise you will receive an error.
use     res = c() before the loop starts.
With more context more help can be given. If you can give an example of how the output will look that is very helpful.

Comment: Seems like you want to split `res` into two seperate matrices. If so, it might be a good idea to delete all the unnecessary code and just provide the relevant `dput(res)` (or an excerpt of it).

Comment: Thanks for the reply zacdev, Expected output is two different matrices one contains  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
  [1,] "1"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E" 
  [2,] "1"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E"  "E" 
  And another contains their respective values [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]      [,7]      [,8]
  [1,] 54.53939  54.53939  54.53939  54.53939  54.53939  54.53939  54.53939  54.53939
  [2,] 55.78143  55.78143  55.78143  55.78143  55.78143  55.78143  55.78143  55.78143

Answer (score 0):

Finally Found the Way
Written loop which calls function as follows (I dont know if this is a right way or not but It worked for me :p)

```
for(i in 1:300){
days1=c(rnorm(8,mean=56,sd=3))
days=cumsum(days1)
a <- getMedData (med,days)
for(j in 1:length(days)){
    resVal[i,j] = a[[1]][j]
    resProb[i,j] = a[[2]][j]
}}
```